# bash's who command

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to capture&analyze the IDLE time for users in a python script, as obtained by the who command.

My problem is that who's time output is a mess - some examples given:

```
1.00s
47:49
-
9days
```

... and I possibly left out some of them. There is some way of converting it to something that can be analysed easier? Or where do I find the documentation on this time format?

An additional question: since I'm cross-developing my prog on linux and osx, I found out that OSX's who has an additional '-i' switch, which orders output by idle time. Since I need to find the most recently executed shell command, do you know if on linux something similar to 'who -i' exists?

thank you!

---

a word to clarify: my script at the end returns the current working directory of the terminal that executed last.

I didnt find a more elegant way to do it than to execute in sequence the commands:

ps e -o pid,tty,comm (to find the bash'es)

ls -l /proc/'+pid+'/cwd' (to find the CWDs)

w (to sort by time)

... so 'w' is needed last to find which shell'cwd to return

Answer (score 2):

Python's os module really has such a function. It's called `getlogin()`, see here: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getlogin

Regarding your update:

There is also a `getcwd()` available: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd

But I'm not fully understanding what you are really trying to do, so I can't tell whether this two functions is all you need.

Comment: thanks for the help. I simply want my program to be 'aware' of what is happening at the same time in other terminals: it has to be able to read the CWD of the terminal that was used last.